# UIButton title not updating until animation is complete

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` and I am trying to change its title during a left-flip `UIView` transition:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.button1, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.button1.setTitle("TITLE CHANGE", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
}, completion: nil);
```

However, when I attempt this the button's label only updates after the transition has occurred.

How would I make the button's label change occur during the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTitle:forControlState:` is not animatable.

Maybe you can animate attributes of the button property `titleLabel`, but in general you cannot predictably manipulate the internal components of UIKit objects.

One solution is to use two buttons and animate the `alpha`.